# Python Change Variable In Place

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was recently learning how to use `random.shuffle` in Python and I was surprised to see that the function shuffles the variable in place without returning anything. How is this acheived in the function? Looking at the random library's source code yielded no answer.

How can I write my own function that changes the variable in place without reassignment?

Comment: A function can *change the state* of its arguments, but it can't replace the arguments with new objects. Imagine an argument you pass to a function is a post-it on a rope. The function can write new things on the post-it, but it can't untie the rope and tie it to a banana.

Comment: than how does random.shuffle do this?

Comment: A list's contents are part of its state. `random.shuffle` doesn't replace the list with a new list; it changes the list's state.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I is works because of lists are mutable. You cant reassign any variable because it will be new variable. You cant modify immutable typed variable. You can modify mutable variable.

So:

```
>>> def addone(x):
...     x += 1
>>> a = 2
>>> addone(a)
>>> a
2
>>> def addone(x):
...     x.append(1)
... 
>>> l=[2]
>>> addone(l)
>>> l
[2, 1]
>>> def addone(x):
...     x = x + [1]
... 
>>> li=[2]
>>> addone(li)
>>> li
[2]
```

Comment: This is the information I was looking for, now I know what to look into (mutable types) kudos

Answer (score 1):

Well, just look at the implementation of `random.shuffle`.  Find it in a file called `random.py`, it's a pure python implementation and quite simple - just using a loop of assignments (with tuple unpacking).

```
def shuffle(self, x, random=None, int=int):
    """x, random=random.random -> shuffle list x in place; return None.

    Optional arg random is a 0-argument function returning a random
    float in [0.0, 1.0); by default, the standard random.random.

    Do not supply the 'int' argument.
    """

    if random is None:
        random = self.random
    for i in reversed(xrange(1, len(x))):
        # pick an element in x[:i+1] with which to exchange x[i]
        j = int(random() * (i+1))
        x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
```

Comment: yes, but how does this change the value without the return statement?

Comment: it is re-assigning x without returning it

Comment: It doesn't need to return it.  The object x is mutable, so it is modified in place.